# Can expressjs be faster if I compile it?

Tags: node.js, performance, express

There are tools that help us now to compile or node.js apps into executable such as "pkg". But I am interested If this can improve a web server written in expressjs?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, web servers based on the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com) will always require running on the [V8 JavaScript engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/) of Node.js, which is also used by the Google Chrome browser.

You cannot compile a JavaScript program to machine code and run it standalone, like you can with programs written in C++.

If you create an executable program with JavaScript, for example using [Electron](https://electron.atom.io), it's actually just a modified Chrome browser that runs the JavaScript, so the JavaScript is not actually compiled, it is still code interpreted by the modified Chrome's V8 engine at runtime.

Chrome and its V8 engine *are* written in C++ and compiled to machine code, so they *can* be run standalone.